# Find list with minimum cumulative sum of tuple item

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of type `List<List<Tuple<int, int, double>>`.

Semantically, it works like this:

- Each tuple describe a coordinate (i,j) and a measured value (the `double`).
- Each list of tuples describe a trajectory. Its `Sum(t => t.Item3)` describe the *energy* along the trajectory (integral of discrete values).

Now I want to find which sublist has the least energy. I tried the code below, but that gives me the lowest *value*, whereas I want the *list* itself which has the lowest value.

```
var minimum_path = all_paths.Min(c => c.Sum(p => p.Item3));

 ^___ "var" is of type double, should be List<Tuple<...>>
```

Comment: I know it's not the question but Tim has already answered it quite well... My thought is : List<List<Tuple... what an awful thing for brain ! Couldn't you make a dedicated type ?

Comment: @Richard agreed... Most probably I will apply the accepted answer with a more dedicated type...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to order by the sum:

```
List<Tuple<int, int, double>> minList = all_paths
   .OrderBy(l => l.Sum(t => t.Item3))
   .First();
```

If you want to get the list which contains the minimum `Item3` overall instead:

```
List<Tuple<int, int, double>> minList = all_paths
   .OrderBy(l => l.Min(t => t.Item3))
   .First();
```

You could also group by that  to find also other lists with this value:

```
List<List<Tuple<int, int, double>>> allMinLists = all_paths
      .GroupBy(l => l.Sum(t => t.Item3))
      .OrderBy(g => g.Key)
      .First()
      .ToList();
```

Comment: I think that's it... Actually I have already used that before, but one not always remember these tricks. Very idiomatic, thanks!

Comment: `You have to order by the sum` No, you don't.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an `O(n)` solution (in the number of lists) that only iterates the parent list once:

```
var minList = all_paths
    .Aggregate((x, y) => x.Sum(i => i.Item3) < y.Sum(i => i.Item3) ? x : y);
```

Comment: This performs up to twice as many sums as you need to, as you end up continually re-summing the accumulator, even if you've already summed it.  Assuming the groups being summed aren't particularly small, this is likely to perform worse than many of the other solutions presented.

Comment: Yeah, [Alex's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25869414/215380) second block is a good optimization of this. Just making the point that ordering the whole list is *not* necessary just to find the minimum or maximum.

Comment: The best solution would be to simply use `MinBy` from MoreLINQ, or a comparable implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Orderby has O(n^2) complexity, so I guess this variant should be better due to 3*n passes and single evaluation of `Sum()` function instead of calculation for every comparision in `OrderBy` processing:

```
var pathsWithEnergy = all_paths.Select(c => new {Value = c, Energy = c.Sum(p => p.Item3)}).ToList();
var minimum_energy = pathsWithEnergy.Min(x => x.Energy);
var minimum_path = pathsWithEnergy.Find(x => x.Energy == minimum_energy);
```

if lists are big so better way is combine my soultion and @Rawling 's

```
var minList = all_paths.Select(c => new {Value = c, Energy = c.Sum(p => p.Item3)})
                       .Aggregate((x, y) => x.Energy < y.Energy ? x : y).Value;
```

in my bench this solution is 2x faster than original solution with "brute-aggregate".

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var all_paths = new List<List<Tuple<int, int, double>>>();
        const int n = 4000;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            var tuples = new List<Tuple<int, int, double>>();
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            {
                tuples.Add(new Tuple<int, int, double>(i, j, (n + i)*j));
            }
            all_paths.Add(tuples);
        }

        var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        var minList = MinList1(all_paths);
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", minList[0], sw.Elapsed);
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        GC.Collect();
        var sw2 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        var minList2 = MinList2(all_paths);
        sw2.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", minList2[0], sw2.Elapsed);
    }


    private static List<Tuple<int, int, double>> MinList1(List<List<Tuple<int, int, double>>> all_paths)
    {
        return all_paths.Select(c => new {Value = c, Energy = c.Sum(p => p.Item3)})
                        .Aggregate((x, y) => x.Energy < y.Energy ? x : y).Value;
    }

    private static List<Tuple<int, int, double>> MinList2(List<List<Tuple<int, int, double>>> all_paths)
    {
        return all_paths.Aggregate((x, y) => x.Sum(i => i.Item3) < y.Sum(i => i.Item3) ? x : y);
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If your app is performance sensitive, I'd suggest you forget about LINQ(except `Sum` :)).

```
private static List<Tuple<int, int, double>> GetMinimumPath(List<List<Tuple<int, int, double>>> all_paths)
{
    double minSum = double.MaxValue;
    List<Tuple<int, int, double>> minSumPath = null;

    foreach (var path in all_paths)
    {
        double curSum = path.Sum(t => t.Item3);
        if (curSum < minSum)
        {
            minSum = curSum;
            minSumPath = path;
        }
    }

    return minSumPath;
}
```

Or, you can implement a generic [MinBy(morelinq source)](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/MinBy.cs) and use it as:

```
var minimum_path = all_paths.MinBy(path => path.Sum(t => t.Item3));
```